# Angularjs variable value is not updating first time with sweetAlert is success

Tags: angularjs, sweetalert, sweetalert2

> I used AngularJS v1.5.3 & vendor.bundle.js and app.bundle.js

in this click to show button and display swal confirm box and i pressed to 'Yes, display it!' button and div is not display but, i press second time then display this div, i mean $scope.displayDiv value is changing but no any effects of first time
please give me solution

Here i paste my code:

```
<div class="input-group" ng-show="displayDiv" >
        DOM data
</div>
<button class="" ng-click="disDiv()">Show</button>


    $scope.displayDiv=0;
    $scope.disDiv = function() {
            swal({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't to display",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, display it!',
                cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                buttonsStyling: false
            }).then(function() {
                $scope.displayDiv=1;
            });
        };
```

Comment: please dont use the angular tag on angularjs related questions

Comment: success event not in angular world. user $scope.$apply

Comment: thanks a lot 'seyfside', it's working properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try with below function may be help.

```
<div class="input-group" ng-show="displayDiv" >
        DOM data
</div>
<button class="" ng-click="disDiv()">Show</button>


    $scope.displayDiv=0;
    $scope.disDiv = function() {
            swal({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't to display",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, display it!',
                cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                buttonsStyling: false
            }).then(function() {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.displayDiv=1;
                    });
            });
        };
```

> I have add below function in .then
>
> $scope.$apply(function () {
>                           $scope.displayDiv=1;
>                       });